# Calling JQueryUI from Gridview rowcommand inside Updatepanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, jquery-ui-dialog

I've been stuck with this for some time now. I've been surfing stackoverflow for different approches to the problem but I still can't get it to work. It runs the code but the popup wont show. It works when I put the method on a button outside the updatepanel.

I want a popup to display when I click a buttonfield in the gridview.

Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowPopup(message, title) {
            $(function () {
                $("#dialog").html(message);
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    title: title,
                    buttons: {
                        Close: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    },
                    modal: true
                });
            });
        };
</script>

<div id="dialog" style="display: none">

</div>
```

Codebehind(I kept my different approaches to my problem as comments):

```
protected void grdWallmessages_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string message = "Meddelande borttaget från väggen!";
    string title = " Borttagning";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updwallmessages, updwallmessages.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "ShowPopup('" + message + "','" + title + "');", true);

  //  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('File already exists.');", true);
 //     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + "','" + title + "');", true);
    try
    {
        DAL dal = new DAL();
        //Hämtar row index.
        int rowNum = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(grdWallmessages.Rows[rowNum].Cells[3].Text);
        dal.delete_wallmessages(id);


  //      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + "','" + title + "');", true);


        Response.Redirect("Profile.aspx");



    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

The gridview and updatepanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updwallmessages" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:GridView ID="grdWallmessages" runat="server" Height="159px" style="margin-top: 18px; margin-right: 0px;" Width="396px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowCommand="grdWallmessages_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grdWallmessages_RowDataBound">
         <Columns>
             <asp:ButtonField Text="Ta bort" />
         </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not make `Response.Redirect("Profile.aspx");` in a ajax context, which is executed when you keep your grid view code inside UpdatePanel.

Check the server response data, with the help of Firebug or Chrome/Firefox network console.

Comment: @user3025336, That is great :)